# How can I generate the set of all numbers that are two greater than the numbers in another SymPy set?

Tags: set, sympy

If I have a SymPy Set such as:

```
y=FiniteSet(-3,3)
```

and I want to generate another set that is the set of all numbers that are 2 more than the numbers in Set y, how can I do this? I tried a ConditionalSet:

```
ConditionalSet(x,x-2 in y, S.Reals)
```

But that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

To do this with ConditionSet you should use Contains:

```py
In [1]: y = {-3, 3}

In [2]: z = ConditionSet(x, Contains(x-2, y), Reals)

In [3]: z
Out[3]: {x │ x ∊ ℝ ∧ (x - 2 ∈ {-3, 3})}
```

It's better to use ImageSet for this case though:

```py
In [6]: z2 = ImageSet(Lambda(x, x+2), y)

In [7]: z2
Out[7]: {x + 2 │ x ∊ {-3, 3}}

In [8]: z2.doit()
Out[8]: {-1, 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

AHA! I found the answer:

```
[x+2 for x in y]
```

Produces the desired set.

Comment: That's a list rather than a Python set or a SymPy symbolic Set. I thought you were trying to do something more complicated but if you just wanted the list this is fine. My answers apply symbolically for any SymPy Set whereas this will only work for a FiniteSet or a finite iterable Set.